# Change to Django code gives NameError name (function) is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django project where the model has two classes - Equity and Article. Within the Equity class I used to have the following code which worked smoothly

```
def fundamental_list_actual(self):
        l_fund = []
        filtered_articles = Article.objects.filter(equity__industry = self.industry)
        for filtered_article in filtered_articles:
            if(filtered_article.equity.equity_name == self.equity_name):
                l_fund.append([filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
            else:
                if (filtered_article.read_through == -1):
                    l_fund.append([float(-1)*filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
                if (filtered_article.read_through == 1):
                    l_fund.append([filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
        return l_fund
```

However, I recently updated my code to include the following in the model code but outside any class:

```
filename = 'fake_nums_trial_covar'
#infile = open(filename, 'rb')
infile = open('PATH_HIDDEN_FOR_PRIVACY/fake_nums_trial_covar', 'rb')
covar_trial_nums = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

And within the Equity class, the following:

```
def covars_abs_above_mean(row_index):
        covars = covar_trial_nums #cov_to_dataframe('Russel_1000_tickers_3.xlsx')
        stocks = covars.index 
        pos_relation_list = []
        neg_relation_list = []
        pos, neg = avg_pos_and_neg(row_index)
        for stock in stocks:
            if (covars.loc[row_index, stock] > pos):
                pos_relation_list.append(stock)
            if (covars.loc[row_index, stock] < neg):
                neg_relation_list.append(stock)
        return pos_relation_list, neg_relation_list


def fundamental_list(self):
        name = self.equity_name
        pos_related_cos, neg_related_cos = covars_abs_above_mean(name)

        #now we want to get a list of articles whose equity__equity_name matches that of ANY
        #of the equities in our pos / neg lists (though we'd like 2 separate filters for this)
        #try:
        pos_filtered = Article.objects.filter(equity__equity_name__in = pos_related_cos)
        neg_filtered = Article.objects.filter(equity__equity_name__in = neg_related_cos)
        l_fund = []
        filtered_articles_industry = Article.objects.filter(equity__industry = self.industry)
    
        for filtered_article in filtered_articles_industry:
            if (filtered_article.equity.equity_name == self.equity_name):
                l_fund.append([filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
            else:
                if (filtered_article.read_through == -1):
                    l_fund.append([float(-1)*filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
                if (filtered_article.read_through == 1):
                    l_fund.append([filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
        for filtered_article in pos_filtered:
            if (filtered_article.equity.industry != self.industry):
                l_fund.append([filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
        for filtered_article in neg_filtered:
            if (filtered_article.equity.industry != self.industry):
                l_fund.append([float(-1)*filtered_article.get_fun_score(), filtered_article.get_date(), filtered_article.id, filtered_article.title, filtered_article.get_source()])
        
        return l_fund
```

However, whenever I run the code on the local server 127.0.0.1:8000, some pages work fine but some give me an error and state at the bottom: "pos_related_cos, neg_related_cos = covars_abs_above_mean(name)" and says "Name 'covars_abs_above_mean' is not defined." Powershell displays a similar error. However, I thought I did define it...right above in the code? Further, a separate file I used to "test" out the covariance matrix on my Desktop works fine, it seems the error appears only once I start getting into Django. I am not great at Django and any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I had to add this function in to my code as a helper,

```
def avg_pos_and_neg(self, row_index):
        covar = covar_trial_nums 
        row = covar[row_index]
        pos_list = []
        neg_list = []
        for ind in row.index:
            if (row[ind] > 0):
                pos_list.append(row[ind])
            if (row[ind] < 0):
                neg_list.append(row[ind])
        pos_avg = 0
        neg_avg = 0
        for item in pos_list:
            pos_avg += item
        for item in neg_list:
            neg_avg += item
        pos_avg = pos_avg / len(pos_list)
        neg_avg = neg_avg / len(neg_list)
        return pos_avg, neg_avg
```

and whenever I load a page it just loads forever. The page seems like it'll take forever to load and it doesn't give me an error page, or the page that I want - just loading...

Answer (score 1):

It is not function but a class method so you should call it properly

```
self.covars_abs_above_mean(name)
```

Comment: Sorry, for the previous comments I realized I can't put code in my comments. I made an Edit in my original post, i dont know how to resolve from there.